# Why is the angular controller syntax different in the Ionic documentation from W3schools ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

On the w3schools Angular controller section you're instructed to write a controller like this:

instantiate a module first:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

In the ionic docs when you use a delegate however you're instructed to make your controllers like this:

> function ContentController($scope, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {
>   $scope.toggleLeft = function() {
>       $ionicSideMenuDelegate.toggleLeft();   }; }

are there completely different controllers in ionic than there are in angular?

Comment: Both are valid ways to define controllers, the first one being better as it does't pollute the global environment

Comment: so declaring a function the second way places it in the global scope. I wonder if there's a reason Ionic prefers it that way.

Comment: Might be for beginner's convenience. You can use the other way too: http://mcgivery.com/controllers-ionicangular/